# 3 border-bottoms for a single div?

Tags: css

Is there a way to create 3 `border-bottom`s to a single `div`?

Here is what it needs to look like:

[image]

Comment: The completely cross-browser easy solution would be to use three elements. The fancy-pancy CSS3 solution would be to use box-shadow, which supports a comma seperated list, and take as many shadows as you want.

Comment: A downvote without a comment is not appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogzoQQ

```
<div id="box"></div>  

#box{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:blue;
box-shadow: 0px 3px  green,0px 6px  orange,0px 9px  yellow;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: good Now its possible to apply three shadows, what abt border .?

Comment: @NaveenKumarPG you can do it but that is a lot of work http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbGzyr

Answer (score 0):

You can try to approach this with border double, border-radius and shadow.

```
.class {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-bottom: 3px double #BBBBBB;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(187,187,187, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get this effect using

```
border-bottom: 3px double #BBBBBB;"
```

if you want three lines you need to use three different divs with

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
```

fro three containers. for the last div give shadow effect.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYjOzm) is one method to achieve above output.

**HTML**

```
<div class="borderBox">
  <div class="innerCnt">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.innerCnt {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.innerCnt ul {
  margin: 0
}
.borderBox {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
.borderBox:after,
.borderBox:before {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 1px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.borderBox:after {
  top: 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```